# How to move a point from a PostgreSQL point layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, editing, move

I have a table in PostgreSQL. The table includes geometries in 2 columns. The two geometries are the startpoint and endpoint. If I want to move one of the points in QGIS, is not allowed. If I save the point layer as a shp file, I can move the point.

How it is possible to move the points (edit the position) in QGIS and save the new position in the database?

Comment: What do you mean by not allowed, do you get error?

Comment: Icon for moving is disabled. But i can create a new point. The database must have the rights for editing.  If i Export the layer to a shp file the moving icon is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS need a primary key !

```
alter table t_geom_test add id serial not null;
alter table t_geom_test add primary key (id);
```

After that works to edit the Points.